# Table with input checkbox check/Uncheck

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have a problem when doing the check in the accompanying table with color style works very well except when i click the first any checkbox does not change color style.

I paste the code and i use only javascript pure.

```
enter function valid(chk){
    var trckk = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    var parent = chk.parentNode.parentNode;
    var chkcomite = document.getElementsByName('idcom');
    var len = chkcomite.length;
    for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
        if(chkcomite[i].checked === true){
            if(chkcomite[i]!=chk && chk.checked){
                chkcomite[i].checked = false;
                for(var i=0;i<trckk.length;i++){
                    trckk[i].style.background='';
                    trckk[i].style.color='';
                }
            }
            parent.style.background='#EC1C24';
            parent.style.color='#FFF';  
        }else{
            parent.style.background='';
            parent.style.color='';
        }
    }
}
```

here

Can you help me?.
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must write the function like this

```js
function valid(chk) {
  var parent = chk.parentNode.parentNode;
  if (!chk.checked) {
    parent.style.background = "";
    parent.style.color = "";
    return;
  }
  var trckk = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  var chkcomite = document.getElementsByName("idcom");
  var len = chkcomite.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < trckk.length; i++) {
    trckk[i].style.background = "";
    trckk[i].style.color = "";
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    chkcomite[i].checked = false;
    chkcomite[i].parentNode.parentNode.style.background = "";
    chkcomite[i].parentNode.parentNode.style.color = "";
  }
  chk.checked = true;
  parent.style.background = "#EC1C24";
  parent.style.color = "#FFF";
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      row 1
    </td>
    <td>
      <input onchange="valid(this)" name="idcom" type='checkbox'>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      row 2
    </td>
    <td>
      <input onchange="valid(this)" name="idcom" type='checkbox'>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      row 3
    </td>
    <td>
      <input onchange="valid(this)" name="idcom" type='checkbox'>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks you much!.. it is agreeable.